# I'm trying to Insert values using GUI in jdbc through mysql database it's giving me the following Exception:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Exception:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near ''Name','ID') VALUES('','')' at line 1

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        String Name="Jack";
        int ID = 21;
        String q="insert into student values(?,?)";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student", "root", "");

        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(q);
        st.setString(1,Name);
        st.setString(2,ID);

        int c=st.executeUpdate();
       System.out.print(c);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Name','ID') VALUES('','')' at line 1

Comment: You should use `st.executeUpdate()` **without** parameters

Comment: yeah, tried doing that but it's inserting the values through the code not from the GUI fields

Comment: So, the code you currently show in your question is working? If so, it is unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: an alternative worked! Thank you though.